# What is the correct possessive form of names ending in "x"?

Tags: possessives, saxon-genitive

The title says it all.

Should one use *Theroux's works* or *Theroux' works*? *The Phoenix's Egg* or *The Phoenix' Egg*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different sources say different things. Wikipedia [sums it up as follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Nouns_ending_with_silent_.E2.80.9Cs.2C.E2.80.9D_.E2.80.9Cx.E2.80.9D_or_.E2.80.9Cz.E2.80.9D):

> The English possessive of French nouns ending in a silent *s*, *x*, or *z* is rendered differently by different authorities. Some prefer *Descartes'* and *Dumas'*, while others insist on *Descartes's* and *Dumas's*. Certainly a sibilant is pronounced in these cases; the theoretical question is whether the existing final letter is sounded, or whether *s* needs to be added. Similar examples with *x* or *z*: *Sauce Périgueux's main ingredient is truffle; His pince-nez's loss went unnoticed; “Verreaux('s) eagle, a large, predominantly black eagle*, Aquila verreauxi,...” (OED, entry for “Verreaux”, with silent *x*; see [Verreaux's eagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verreaux%27s_eagle)); in each of these some writers might omit the added *s*. The same principles and residual uncertainties apply with “naturalised” English words, like *Illinois* and *Arkansas*.
>
> For possessive plurals of words ending in silent *x*, *z* or *s*, the few authorities that address the issue at all typically call for an added *s*, and require that the apostrophe precede the *s*: *The Loucheux's homeland is in the Yukon; Compare the two Dumas's literary achievements*. The possessive of a cited French title with a silent plural ending is uncertain: “*Trois femmes's* long and complicated publication history”, but “*Les noces'* singular effect was 'exotic primitive'...” (with nearby sibilants *-ce-* in noces and *s-* in singular).

Comment: Did you notice the unencylopedic bias nearly to the point of peeving in the way they’ve opposed “prefer” with “insist”?  Tsk.  People like Camus have the same problem as Dumas has, of course.